# Code returns column name but column count is zero in Kotlin

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, cursor, android-sqlite

I'm trying to fetch the whole data in a  database and this is my code that does that.

```
private fun readAllPoetsDB(): Cursor {
            val db = readableDatabase
            return db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM INFO",null)
        }

        fun readAllPoets(): ArrayList<Poet> {
            val poets = ArrayList<Poet>()
            val cursor = readAllPoetsDB()
            println("this is cursor count")
            println(cursor.count)
            println(cursor.getColumnName(0))
            var poetid: String
            var faname: String
            var enname: String
            cursor.moveToNext()
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast) {
                    poetid = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBPoet.UserEntry.COLUMN_POET_ID))
                    faname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBPoet.UserEntry.COLUMN_FANAME))
                    enname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBPoet.UserEntry.COLUMN_ENNAME))
                    poets.add(Poet(poetid, faname, enname))
                     cursor.moveToNext()
            }
            cursor.close()
            return poets
        }
```

the line `println(cursor.count)` returns zero but `cursor.getColumnName` returns the right name.
Please don't forget that I have checked my table name and it is 100% correct.
Also, my database file is local and it is not getting created inside the app, it is added manually.
So what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

From `Cursor.java`:
`cursor.count` (`getCount()`) returns the number of **rows** returned by the `Cursor`.
`cursor.columnCount` (`getColumnCount()`) returns the number of **columns** in the `Cursor`.

Comment: but my database has 3 rows. and cursor.count is returning zero 
what is causing that?

Comment: Can you print the rows inside the while loop? If nothing is printed and cursor.count returns 0 then the table is empty.

Comment: that's exactly what happens but the table is not empty. it's a local file and i can view it .

Comment: What do you mean local? It should be in the device/emulator. Extract it and check if it is empty or not.

Comment: by local I mean it's added manually by me to the project it self. and it has 43 rows and 3 columns field with data.

Comment: to the assest folder inside the project.

Comment: Your code does not access the database in the assets folder. It accesses the database in the `/data/data/<yourpackagename>/databases/` folder in the device. You must copy the database from assets to the device.

Comment: databases folder should be inside the assests folder. shouldn't it? 
also if my code couldn't read the database it would not be able to print out the column names correctly.

Comment: The assets folder is inside the apk file of your application. The apk file is not updatable. A database is updatable (you can do inserts, updates, deletes). It is common practice to have a database prepopulated inside the assets folder and by the1st run of the app copy it in the databases folder in the device and work on that database.

Comment: Use the `Device File Explorer` of Android Studio and find the database in the `/data/data/<yourpackagename>/databases/` folder. Extract it in your pc and open it to verify that the table is empty.

Comment: thanks for your help. I did as you said and the database is not empty at all.

Comment: The table `INFO` that your code accesses is empty because `cursor.count` returns `0` (as you say) if the cursor uses this sql statement: `"SELECT * FROM INFO"`. So if you are sure that the table `INFO` in the database inside the folder: `/data/data/<yourpackagename>/databases/` is **not** empty then the problem is somewhere else in your code. My answer was about the question as you posted it: the difference between `count` and `columnCount` which you missed.